# Looking for 3-D rotating Cube-ActionScript 2.0 code

Tags: flash, actionscript, 3d, actionscript-2, cube

We are looking for the Flash ActionScript 2.0 code for a 3-D rotating cube to be used to display ads on a website. Any ideas where to start?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of libraries out there, but I once managed to work with lo9ic.  It seemed like the most comprehensive, but that was about a year and a half ago...  Not sure if they are still around, as Google does not point to their website anymore.  I still have the source if you're interested.

And here is an article from Adobe on this topic:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/3d_classes.html

Comment: Yeah, if you can provide the source, awesome!

Comment: I need a place to send it.  Do you have an Email address/upload location?

Comment: You can drop it at Drop.io Once uploaded, you can just post link. Again, thank you very much